# Erlang : Conditions involving user-defined functions on objects that are not pattern-matchable

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, user-defined-functions

In an Erlang code, I am using a dictionary like data structure which has a list of {tag, value}. eg: {robot, **[{x-pos, 50}, {y-pos, 100}, {speed, 10}]**. The number of elements in the list or it's order cannot be predicted. I have written functions that will traverse the list to find values of each parameter like get_xpos, get_ypos ,etc.

I want to write a function which should behave like this

```
function(MyTuple) when get_xpos (MyTuple) > 50 -> stop;
function(MyTuple) when get_ypos (MyTuple) < 50 -> forward.
```

As **user-defined functions** are not permitted in guards or if in Erlang, this is not possible. As there are many conditions like this, it won't be elegant to write case statements for each of these conditions. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Are these two clauses? If so they should be separated with a semicolon, otherwise it's a syntax error.

Comment: Also Tuple is a misleading variable name. TupleList would be a better candidate.

Comment: `fun` is a reserved word used for defining anonymous function objects. It can't be used as a name for functions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I was translating the code from Haskell and trying to reduce the complexity, hence the errors. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
aux_fun(TupleList) -> fun(get_xpos(TupleList), get_ypos(TupleList)).

fun(XPos, YPos) when XPos > 50 -> stop;
fun(XPos, YPos) when YPos < 50 -> forward.
```

Comment: You are using a seemingly undefined `fun/3` in `aux_fun/1`.

Comment: `fun` is a reserved word used for defining anonymous function objects. It can't be used as a name for functions.

Comment: It was used in his examples, that's why I used it too.

Comment: There are many functions like get_xpos, get_ypos etc., and in some cases the corresponding values might not even be present in myTuple(I would code the function handling this situation). Hence it won't be possible to pass all them as arguments.